# Get the detail of employee by its name

Tags: java, arrays

```
List<Employee> employee=new ArrayList<Employee>();
static final  String[] mylist=new String[3];


employee.add(new Employee("Sofia","London","092237674643","Manager",30,800000));
employee.add(new Employee("Jones","Qwait","092013764551","CEO",33,20000000));
employee.add(new Employee("Kai","Korea","5243524541741","Staff",43,700000));

n=new String[]{"Wazma","Laiba","Kainat","Sana","Sara","Saba","Ayesha","Ali","Armeena","Ahmed"};
for(int i=0;i<employee.size();i++){
            mylist[i]=String.valueOf(employee.get(i));


        }
Iterator<Employee> itr=employee.iterator();
Employee emp;    
for(int j=0;j<mylist.length;j++){

             emp = itr.next();

             if(emp.getName().matches(mylist[j])) {
             System.out.println(mylist[j]);

                    }
```

What i am trying to do is check if the name in mylist matches the name in emp then print the detail of that employee. but my code on if condition goes back to for loop instead of printing the detail.

Answer (score 0):

For that you have to store value of `name` in your String[] array (myList) instead of storing the whole Employee object as String. So make following changes to your for loop where you are initializing that array:

```
for(int i=0;i<employee.size();i++){
        mylist[i]=employee.get(i).getName();
}
```

Now `getName()` should be a getter method of your Employee class.

Answer (score 0):

There are few things not clear in your question - what is the purpose of `String[] n` ( its not properly declared anyway) and why are you putting employee names into `String[]` then searching same names again?

If you have a `List` of `Employee` objects , lets say `employees` and you want to find employees from this list who matches names from any separate list of names then below java - 8 code will help ,

```
List<Employee> result = employees.stream().filter( emp -> tobeFoundNames.contains(emp.getName())).collect(Collectors.toList());

results.forEach( result -> System.out.println(result.getName()));
```

here , `tobeFoundNames` is another `List<String>`  that contains list of names that you are searching for.

like - `List<String> tobeFoundNames = Arrays.asList("Wajid","Sofia");`

Result is a `List<Employee>` because there might be multiple matches.

Its assumed that `Employee` object has a method - `getName()`.